# Not able to locate chef pem files

Tags: chef-infra, chefdk

I installed Chef Development Kit. But I am unable to locate chef.pem and chef-validator.pem files in any directory. I tried through ls command as well. Need help.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your `knife.rb`?

Comment: I got it. I think we do not need these pem files now. Chef dk is running without issues now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3):

You get those files from your Chef Server. You don't actually need the validation key anymore so you can ignore that one, and your use key can be found either from the web UI or is printed to the console when you make the user via `chef-server-ctl`.

Comment: Right, I just checked we do not need these files anymore. I am using chef dk without any issue now. Thank you!

Comment: You do need the user key, just for clarity.

Comment: Right now I am stuck at a new problem. I installed chefbook using chef generate cookbook chefbookname

Comment: Right now I am stuck at a new problem. I installed cookbook using chef generate cookbook cookbookname, and it says it is installed successfully. But when I try to run recipes using runlist, it fails by giving error of missing cookbooks. I am attaching the screenshot in answer section.

Comment: Please create a new question if you have a new question to ask.

Comment: Also if you want more interactive help getting started with Chef, try https://community-slack.chef.io/ or a Chef training class.